# How can I delete multiple rows under pandas ta column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I want to delete the data named volvo and dodge belonging to the make column. However, although I tried all kinds of functions, I still couldn't remove the data I didn't want from the column.how can I do that. I should delete or show multiple data at once. Very Thank you.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

csv_path = "traffic-crashes-vehicles-1.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

filter_data1= data[['MAKE']]

filter_data2 = filter_data1[filter_data1.isin(['DODGE','VOLVO'])].dropna()
```

DATAFRAME:

```
                                                  MAKE  VEHICLE_YEAR
                    0                            DODGE        2011.0
                    1                            VOLVO        2020.0
                    2                          UNKNOWN           NaN
                    3       TOYOTA MOTOR COMPANY, LTD.        2015.0
                    4                           SUBARU        2014.0
                    ...                            ...           ...
                    700461                      NISSAN        2013.0
                    700462               MERCEDES-BENZ        2016.0
                    700463                       DODGE        2018.0
                    700464             KIA MOTORS CORP        2013.0
                    700465                       LEXUS        2014.0
```

Comment: what's `asd` in your code?

Comment: very sory. I'am edit now :)

Comment: just `data.loc[data['MAKE'].isin(['DODGE', 'VOLVO'])]`?

Comment: I can already do this. What I want is to delete volvo and dodge data.

Comment: negation: `data.loc[~data['MAKE'].isin(['DODGE', 'VOLVO'])]`

Comment: very very very very thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close !

```
data = data[~ data['MAKE'].isin(['DODGE','VOLVO'])]
```

should do it